# How to create option in ng2-select2 ajax

Tags: angular

I'm using [ng2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) in my Angular2 project but I have problem that I can't render option in my select2. I get the data but I can't show option in templateResult.

HTML

```
<select2 [options]="options"></select2>
```

TS

```
public options: Select2Options;
public ajaxOptions: any;

public ngOnInit(): void {

    this.ajaxOptions = {
        url: 'https://localhost:8080/ajaxdata/testselect2',
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 500,
        cache: false,
        data: (params: any) => {
            return {
                search: params.term,
                gotoPage: params.page
            };
        },
        processResults: (data: any, params: any) => {
            params.page = params.page || 1;
            return {
                results: data.objectValue.items,
                }),
                pagination: {
                    more: (params.page * 10) < data.objectValue.total_count
                }
            };
        },
    };

    this.options = {
        ajax: this.ajaxOptions,
        templateResult: (object: Select2SelectionObject) => {
            // should create option in here
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. I have json that is not format with select2 so I change my code in processResults like this and remove templateResult it will render the options.

```
processResults: (data: any, params: any) => {
    params.page = params.page || 1;
    return {
        results: $.map(data.objectValue.items, function (obj) {
            return { id: obj.code, text: obj.desc };
        }),
        pagination: {
            more: (params.page * 10) < data.objectValue.total_count
        }
    };
},
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue. It didn't even trigger the AJAX call. How did you get this working?

Comment: I can trigger the AJAX call but I just can't render it to html, Can you show me your code ?

Comment: It is actually kind of copy of your code. Please [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050414/use-ajax-in-ng2-select2). I have posted it in this question