# Use AJAX in ng2-select2

Tags: angularjs, ajax, jquery-select2, angularjs-select2

I have many drop-downs in my angular2js project. I am using [ng2-select2](https://github.com/NejcZdovc/ng2-select2) for these drop-down. In some dropdown, I need to filter and fetch data from an API as per the string user types into the select2 search box. The plug-in initializes but doesn't fire any AJAX.

My code so far:

HTML:

```
<select2 [data]="options | async"></select2>
```

Component:

```
import { Component,OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import {Select2OptionData} from 'ng2-select2';
import {AlertService, LTJService} from '../../_services/index';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
    selector: 'nationalities',
    templateUrl: '../../views/buyer_profile/nationalities.component.html',
})

export class NationalityComponent implements OnInit {
    //public nationalities: Observable<Array<Select2OptionData>>;
    public options: Select2Options;
    public ajaxOptions: Select2AjaxOptions;


    constructor(private alertService: AlertService, private ltjService: LTJService) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        console.log('In ngOnInit');

        this.ajaxOptions = {
            url: '<API URL>',
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            cache: false,
            data: (params: any) => {
                console.log("AA", params);
                return {
                    query: params.term,
                    gotoPage: params.page
                }
            },
            processResults: (data: any, params: any) => {
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                console.log('data: ', data);
                return {
                    results: $.map(data.data, function(obj) {
                        return {id: obj.id, text: obj.name};
                    }),
                    pagination: {
                        more: (params.page * 10) < data.objectValue.total_count
                    }
                };
            },
        };

        this.options = {
            ajax: this.ajaxOptions
        }
    } 
}
```

Can anyone point me into the right direction?
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use [data] which will input only data not option

```
<select2 [data]="options | async"></select2>
```

try

```
<select2 [options]="options | async"></select2>
```

Comment: Yes, it worked and as you said, it is not rendering the HTML. Did you find any work around for this?
Thanks

Comment: it depend on your json response structure. your current code use `{id: obj.id, text: obj.name}` that means you use obj.id as id and obj.name as text. try check your json response

Comment: JSON response is correct but I figured the issue is with API which expects some custom headers in request.
Thanks for your help, really appreciate it.